# Windows 3.11 in DOSBox-X says that “Your network adapter MS$NE2CLONE is not working properly”

Tags: emulation, windows-3.x, troubleshooting, dosbox

I had networking working on Windows 3.11 previously, now I am getting the error "Your network adapter MS$NE2CLONE is not working properly".  I tried reinstalling all the files, changing intercepts for NE2000, to no avail.  I can't seem to find anyone else having this issue.

Dosbox-X Version: DOSBox-X 2023.10.06

[image: A Windows 3.x style error dialog box, entitled “Windows for Workgroups”, with the contents “Your network adapter MS$NE2CLONE is not working properly. You may need to set it up again. For mroe information, see "Troubleshooting" in your "Workgroup Add-On User's Guide."” and a single “OK” button.]

Comment: Do you know what changed since the last time your setup worked?

Comment: So when did it work before? Did you install a newer DosBox-X and it stopped working, while it worked on older DosBox-X? Which version was it?